# How do I display nodes of two different content types that use the same taxonomy term?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have two content types, *typeA* and *typeB*. Both the content types have a taxonomy reference field.

I created a view for each content type. In the view showing *typeA* nodes, I want to show also *typeB* nodes using the same taxonomy term.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Taxonomy views are filtered by the term you are viewing - unless the content was part of both terms I am not sure how you would do this.

Comment: its just the name of the filter that is is the same but the content is different think of it as the same name of an article but one is for the news and other is an event

Comment: and i want to display for example the news of an x article in the event view with the same x article which are events

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The question isn't completely clear as it uses a terminology that isn't correct, in Drupal. In Drupal, taxonomy terms aren't content types. They are associated to nodes, but they aren't nodes nor content types. Also, _I have brand-new/car and old/car and in the view of the brand new one i want to have the old ones too_ isn't clear, since it doesn't say what *brand-new/car* and *old/car* are, what the relationship between *brand-new/car* and *old/car* is, nor (if those are two views) what their settings are.

Comment: there are 2 content types (typeA and typeB) and each of these contents can get a taxonomy for ex : taxo1 taxo2..., and there is a view for each content type A and B, 

what i want is to get in a view of content type A the content type B where the Taxonomy of type A is equal to taxonomy of type B

i'am new in this technology i didn't explain it well the first time